# Integral relationship between a function and its distribution function.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have read an integral equality from certain books such as "Interpolation of Operators". The equality is:
$$\int_{X}|f|d \mu= \int_{0}^{\infty} d_f(t)dt.$$
Where $(X,S,\mu)$ is a sigma finite measure space and $$d_f(t)=\mu(\{x \in X : |f(x)|>t\}).$$
At certain places I saw its proof in which I couldn't find any use of sigma finiteness e.g., see the [Pdf](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.111.1244&rep=rep1&type=pdf). My question is that, is this equality also true if measure space is not sigma finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true even without $\sigma$ finiteness. If LHS is  finite then $f=0$ outside a set of $\sigma$ finite measure and the equality holds. If LHS is $\infty$ then RHS is also  $\infty$ as seen by splitting the integral into integrals over $n \leq f <n+1$ and a fairly standard argument.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm unable to understand your argument properly. How finiteness of integral implies it vanishes outside some set which is sigma finite?

Comment: $\mu\{x:|f(x)>a\}\leq \frac  1a \int |f|d\mu<\infty$ for each  $a >0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x \notin \bigcup_n  \{x:|f(x)>\frac  1n )$. @UserA